# How to make this code involving Hypergeometric functions to run faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, special-functions

This question is followed up [from this Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102042/inverse-laplace-transform). I would like to thank Dr. Hintze and I_Mariusz for the comments and help.
I am pretty new to mathematica ( I just learned it 4 days ago)
so I would like to ask if there is a way to accelerate the following codes :

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq = (2*S0/(y*sigma^2))^
nu*(Gamma[nu + (2*mu)/sigma^2]/Gamma[2*nu + (2*mu)/sigma^2])*
Hypergeometric1F1[nu, 2*nu + (2*mu)/sigma^2, -2*S0/(y*sigma^2)];
int = Integrate[eq, {y, K, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]
int2 = int /. nu -> (-vu/2 + Sqrt[vu^2 + 8*alpha/sigma^2]/2) /. 
 vu -> (2*mu/sigma^2 - 1)

mu = 15/100;
sigma = 5/100;
S0 = 100;
K = 95;
T = 1;
F[alpha_] = int2/alpha;

A = 18.4;
n = 40;
m = 50;
S = ConstantArray[0, m + 1];
B = 1;
For[k = 0, k <= m, k++,
   S[[k + 1]] = Exp[A/2]/(2*B)*Re[F[A/(2*B)]];
   For[j = 1, j <= n + k, j++,
    S[[k + 1]] = 
S[[k + 1]] + Exp[A/2]/B*(-1)^j*Re[F[(A + 2*j*Pi*I)/(2*B)]];
]    ]
f = 0
   For[k = 0, k <= m, k++,
   f = f + Binomial[m, k]*S[[k + 1]]*2^(-m);
   ]
f
```

Currently, it takes me hours to run this program. Thank you so much for your time.  I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I believe that if you change `F[alpha_] = int2/alpha` to `F[alpha_] := int2/alpha` this will run quite quickly. Using `=` in a function assignment doesn't actually assign it as a pattern (see the documentation on Set (=) versus SetDelayed (:=)).

Comment: Thank you ! please let me try .

Comment: If you make that a delayed definition you need to also make `int2` an explicit function of `alpha`.  The other thing I'd suggest is to convert your `For` loop to a `Table[  Sum[] ]` structure.

Comment: george2079 : Thanks ! , let me understand how Table is used. I've have never used it before.

Comment: The other thing you should do here is note you are frequently recomputing `F` for the same argument.  Define `F` so it remembers: `F[alpha_] := F[alpha] = int2[alpha]/alpha;`  ( or restructure your loop so you aren't repeating calculations , that inner `For` loop just adds one new term for each `k`.)

Comment: `K` is a built-in symbol; I do not recommend you using it here as a parameter.

Comment: So what  is the result:  11.094 or  116 ?

Comment: Dear I_Mariusz: Thank you for your attention. I have a follow up question here : http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21582/numerical-inversion-involved-confluent-hypergeometric-1f1-or-kummer-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes about a minute.

```
(* with int2 redefined as : int2[alpha_] = .. *)
F[alpha_] := F[alpha] = int2[alpha]/alpha;
terms = Monitor[ 
  Exp[A/2]/B Table[ (-1)^j*Re[F[(A + 2*j*Pi*I)/(2*B)]] ,
       {j, 0, n + m + 1}], {j}]
S = Accumulate[terms][[n ;;]]
f = Sum[Binomial[m, k]*S[[k + 1]]*2^(-m), {k, 0, m}]
```

I'd encourage you to study this carefully to be sure it is faithful to your calculation.  (I'm sure its close but I could have shifted an index or some such doing it quickly)